# Cannot delete folder with rm -rf. Error: device or resource busy

Tags: debian, directory, rm, var

I'm trying to delete /var/www/html but I'm getting this error:

```
rm: cannot remove `html': Device or resource busy
```

Comment: Long shot, but do you have `/var/www/html` configured as a mount point for another filesystem?

Answer (score 32):

I was having the same issue, I was trying and failing to delete

```
/usr/local/tomcat/data
```

with the error `rm: cannot remove`/usr/local/tomcat/data': Device or resource busy`

until I noticed that `df -h` said

```
/dev/vda3              20G  172M   20G   1% /usr/local/tomcat/data
```

that is, I had a partition mounted to that point. Mystery solved.

Comment: If you want to actually unmount the partition, see advice in this comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11238/how-to-get-over-device-or-resource-busy#comment821528_11241

Answer (score 11):

You can use `lsof` or `fuser` to indentify which is using this directory, something like this:

```
# lsof +D /var/www/html
```

Answer (score 4):

It's likely that there is a process running that is using a file or files found somewhere in the tree below `/var/www/html`

try

```
lsof +D /var/www/html
```

to get a list of the processes using files in the tree. Sample output below shows that a bash shell with PID 8138 is using /var/www/html/iain.

```
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE    NODE NAME
bash    8138 iain  cwd    DIR  253,0 4096 1982790 /var/www/html/iain
```

Comment: Nothing shows up. No errors or anything.

Comment: try `/sbin/fuser -m /var/www/html`