# cannot remove file, Device or resource busy

Tags: process, kill, rm

I tried removing a file. The most relevant answer can be found [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/319727/cannot-delete-folder-with-rm-rf-error-device-or-resource-busy), but I found no luck. Here is the original problem:

```
maxgitt@mgpc:~$ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker/
rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/docker/aufs': Device or resource busy
```

To locate the process I tried the following:

```
maxgitt@mgpc:~$ sudo lsof +D /var/lib/docker/
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
```

So I tried found in a comment in the above answer but found nothing,

```
maxgitt@mgpc:~$ /sbin/fuser -m /var/lib/docker/
bash: /sbin/fuser: No such file or directory
```

Even `ps` couldn't find the process

```
maxgitt@mgpc:~$ ps aux | grep docker
maxgitt   5349  0.0  0.0  14224  1024 pts/18   S+   15:21   0:00 grep --color=auto docker
maxgitt@mgpc:~$
```

Any help on how to kill this mysterious process would be great.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its still mounted. I bet you see it if you run `mount`. If so run the following

```
# umount /var/lib/docker/aufs
# rm -rf /var/lib/docker
```

Comment: so a mounted file system is completely separate from what is considered a running process?

Comment: you can't delete a directory which has a mount hence the resource busy error.. be nice if it told you why it was busy

Answer (score 0):

I had to stop docker with systemctl disable docker and them delete the files inside manually. Hopefully there's a faster way.